# php regex Remove "-s from string

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove "-s that making invalid json, how do I do it in php regex?

> "name": "Steak "au Four" ",

in this situation remove  "au Four"-s " quotes

Comment: I formatted your question so it is better readable. Do you have some code you already tried? You should post that here too, using the edit link under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the php code to match the two quotes within a quote:

```
$re = "/^\"name\": \"[^\"]*?(\")*?[^\"]*?(\")*?[^\"]*?\"$/"; 
$str = "\"Steak \"au Four\" \""; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Sample demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jX9bX0/5)

Comment: it's working , but "name:" must be in regex, can you pls do it to me, i'm newbie

Comment: @NaomiNaomi I added this to the beginning now. But you realize that this only replaces 1 pair of quotes after this string `"name": "`**here**`"`

Comment: (I also made this optional now.) I agree though with @sevavietl's answer below to try and use `str_replace()`, which will replace all instances of the quotes in the `value`.

Comment: One more thing. Can you please add your code that you tried to the question above, so it satisfies the requirements for a question? It is important so that people can see what you tried to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There's no use of matching the quotes with regex for replacing, because the only thing you will end up with is the quotes themselves.

Actually, that is not quite true, as you can get them along with indexes by passing `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` as the forth parameter to the `preg_match()` (you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)).

But again, what if there's **more than two double quotes**. In that case the regex will be more complicated. Then you will have transform the string to the array with `str_split()`, so you can unset elements by index. And finally transform array to string again with `join()` or `implode()` by joining the elements together.

I think easier to grab the whole value and then replace the quotes with `str_replace()`. In you case you can do something like this:

```
$jsonLine = "\"name\":\"Steak \"au Four\" \"";
$jsonLine = trim($jsonLine);

$pattern = '/^(?P<name>"name"\s*:\s*)(?P<value>".*".*")$/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $jsonLine, $matches) === false) {
    exit('Pattern not matched');
}

$name = $matches['name'];
$value = trim(str_replace('"', '', $matches['value']));

$newJsonLine = "$name\"$value\"";

echo $newJsonLine;
```

You can see the demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6a39d88c997bd2e53f543d8e23348bd98352d9c).